# Is it possible to delete anchor tags from a CRUD created with Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I am creating a simple CRUD Board through Express.

I implemented the CRU, but the delete function failed. I used Rails `method='delete'` as a common anchor tag, but Express does not seem to support it.

How can I activate the delete link?

**app.js**

```
...
const board = require("./routes/board");
app.use("/board", board);
...
```

**views**

```
a(href=`/board/${board._id} method="delete"`) 삭제
```

**routes**

```
...
const board = require("../logic/board");
router.delete("/:id", board.delete);
...
```

**logic**

```
...
const Board = require("../db/board");

exports.delete = (req, res) =>{
  Board.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, err => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    res.redirect("/board/index");
  });
}
...
```

And I want to ask. What is the difference in behavior between doing something like `exports.delete = () => {}` and doing something like `module.exports = logic <delete, create etc...>`?

Answer (score 0):

HTML `<a>`nchor tags don't have a `method` attribute -- perhaps you're thinking of `<form>` tags?

> What is the difference in behavior between doing something like `exports.delete = () => {}` and doing something like `module.exports = logic`

The difference is *when* your logic gets executed. The `exports.delete = () => {}` form will export a function that you can execute at some point in the *future*, whereas the `module.exports = Board.findByIdAndRemove()` will execute the database query *immediately* when the file is parsed (which you probably don't want).

Comment: Thank you. I used form as an alternative.

I have a single question. So if you exports a logic file, can not you use routers.get ('show', logic.show) and router.delete ('delete', logic.delete) in routes now?